# React native not detecting Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

When I run `npx react-native doctor` everything seems ok except that it's not recognizing Android studio

[image: npx react-native doctor]

I have the latest Android studio arctic fox installed and I have tried to run the project using Android Studio and it was working.. but when I run the project using `npx react-native run-android` It fails because of the Android environment..

Comment: what happens when you "Press e to try to fix errors." automatically?

Comment: It start downloading android studio ..